# Anyway to use PageInspector in Visual Studio 2012 in ASP.NET MVC3 app?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012

I am using VS2012 Ultimate to work on a ASP.NET MVC3 app and keen on using the new Page Inspector feature. The server side source tracking is not working and diagnostics gives the message:

> ```
> Project must use Razor v2 or later
> ```

The [error messages page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj204395.aspx) says to `Migrate your MVC 3 project to MVC 4 or a later release.`

Is there anyway to do this without upgrading to MVC 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like we can update MVC 3 app to use Razor 2:

http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/using-razor-v2-aspnet-mvc-3

You will not have to update your app to MVC 4, but would need MVC 4 to be installed.

Answer (score -1):

You need to Download MVC4 , that would be the best option i guess.
You can Download MVC4 from  [here](http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/install.aspx?appid=MVC4VS2010)

Comment: Did you read `Is there anyway to do this without upgrading to MVC 4?`